# NoSuchMethodError on onBindViewHolder for cheap phones?

Tags: android

I have got some crash reports saying: `NoSuchMethodError`on my `RecyclerViews` `onBindViewHolder` this only happens for cheap phones like:

```
Event (C5133) 
COSMOTE_MY_TAB_ICS
Lenovo A390 (A390) 
Xperia Miro (ST23i) 
Galaxy Tab2 7.0 (espressorf)
```

Android version for all these devices is: Android 4.0.3 - 4.0.4

**The error stack:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setBackground
    at org.m.muddzboy.QuoteCreator.Background.ColorButtonAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ColorButtonAdapter.java:124)
    at org.m.muddzboy.QuoteCreator.Background.ColorButtonAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ColorButtonAdapter.java:24)
```

**This is my onBindViewHolder:**

which is very simple and dosn't contain that much code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (position == 0) {

        holder.colorButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorpicker2);

    } else {

        gd = (GradientDrawable) App.getAppContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bbtn);
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor(colorslist.get(position)));
        //this crash -> holder.itemView.setBackground(gd);

    }

}
```

So what is the problem? Because my app works perfectly with all non-cheap/chines-phones. Can this be fixed?

Comment: `View#setBackground(Drawable background)` was introduced in API 16, your devices are older

Comment: @pskink how can I support older devices then?

Comment: read the `android.view.View` docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setBackground` method was added in API 16 so if you are testing it on lower than that it will give `NoSuchMethodError`

[Check this link for api level details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

If you want to support it Below `Api 16`. you have used

[setBackgroundDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

like this way

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackgroundDrawable();
} else {
    setBackground();
}
```